# How to trouble-shoot 'critical error' while merging duplicates?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

Using civicrm-5.21.2-wordpress.zip, (and also 5.20), I get a 'crash' ('There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.') for any attempt to merge contacts.

None of the WordPress trouble-shooting info has helped. I don't get any CiviCRM trace-back or debugging data. I don't see anything in the Apache error.log .

Any other suggestions for trouble-shooting this?

Comment: does the civi log have any further details?

Comment: what version of php are you running?

Comment: you can use this extension for easier access to the civicrm logs where there might be some more info
https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Comment: I'm on php 7.2.24. I'm not familiar with civi log, so I'll eagerly install that extension!

Comment: The civi logs don't have any errors for the past several days.

Comment: I don't use wordpress often, that's a wordpress generated error message but I don't know how that relates to civi errors. sorry

Comment: You should get a mail to your site admin address with more detail - what does it say?

Comment: I never got that email. I'm working on 'why' as a separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll dig deeper in another post, but as far as this problem was concerned, I used print and var_dump to trace the problem to

```
public static function getReferencesToTable
.
.
.
$links = $daoClassName::getReferenceColumns();
```

'crashes' because one of the classes was NULL.

While I work on WHY, I got around the crash with a simple:

```
if ( $daoClassName != NULL)
```

wrapper.